# PWM for LED dimming unusual behavior

Tags: c, pic, microchip, pwm

I made a function, where PWM signal is generated at the output (PORTD) without usage of PWM control registers inside PIC microcontroller (PIC18F452). In order to slowly dim LED connected at the output, I was trying to increase the time needed for pulse to advance from 0% of one period to 100% of one period of square wave, while having square wave frequency constant. Everything should go as planned, except that second parameter being passed into `pwm` function, somehow resets, when going from 655 to 666 (that is, when duty cycle is at 65%). After this event, value being passed to `pwm` function proceeds from 0. Where as it should not reset at transition from 655 to 656 but at transition from 1000 to 1001.

```c
void main(void) {
    TRISD = 0x00; //port D set as output
    LATD = 0x00; //port D output set LOW

    unsigned int width = 1000;      // length of T_on + T_off
    unsigned int j;
    unsigned int res;
    while(1){
        for (j = 1; j <= width; j++){
            res = (unsigned int)((j*100)/width);
            pwm(&LATD, res);
        }
    }
    return;
}

void pwm(volatile unsigned char *lat, unsigned int cycle){
    if(cycle > 100){        // reset the "cycle"
        cycle = 100;
    }
    unsigned int i = 1;
    while(i<=(cycle)){    // T_on
        *lat = 0x01;    
        i++;
    }
    unsigned int j = 100-cycle;
    while(j){    // T_off
        *lat = 0;
        j--;
    }
    return;
}
```

As for the program itself, it should work like so:

- second parameter passed into `pwm` function is the duty cycle (in %) which changes from 0 to 100
- with variable "width" the time needed for duty cycle to advance from 0% to 100% is controlled (width = 100 represents fastest time and everything above that is considered gradually slower time from 0% to 100%)
- expression `((j*100)/width)` serves as step variable inside "while" loop inside `pwm` function:

1. if `width = 100`, step is increased every increment of "j"
2. if `width = 1000`, step is increased every 10 increments of "j",
   etc.

- PORTD is passed into function as its address, whereas in function `pwm`, this address is operated via pointer variable `lat`

As for the problem itself, I could only assume two possibilities: either data type of second parameter of function `pwm` is incorrect or there is some unknown limitation within PIC microprocessor.

Also, here are definitions of configuration bits (device specific registers) of PIC, located int header file included in this program: https://i.stack.imgur.com/4ajxD.jpg

This is, how the program should operate: https://vimeo.com/488207207

This is, how the program currently operates: https://vimeo.com/488207746

Comment: Have you switched of the watchdog?

Comment: Have you checked with a debugger?

Comment: @Mike Watchdog set to OFF. I checked debugger, that's how i know the variable passed into ```pwm``` function resets (somehow) at transition from 655 to 656.

Comment: @Mike If curious, you can check edit, where I provided with configuration bits setting. However, I think those definitions are defined as should be. Also I think, there is no problem in hardware (or connections), since bug was spotted in debugger (using MPLAB X).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is a 16 Bit overflow:

```
res = (unsigned int)((j*100)/width);
```

if `j` is greater then 655 the result of the calculation j*100 is greater 16 Bit. Switch this to 32 Bit. Or easier make your loop from 0...100 for `res`.

e.g.

```
for (res = 0; res <= 100; res++){
    pwm(&LATD, res);
}
```

Comment: Haven't tried it yet but I assume ```j/(width/100)``` would work without overflow, when ```j``` goes from 655 to 656?

Comment: @Keno Beware of the integer division `(width / 100)`, it works correctly only for multiples of 100.

Comment: @thebusybee Yeah, I realized that, when implementing code. Now I chose a different approach, which doesnt include division of integer or any division at all.